# WPF: bind my Checkbox IsChecked event to my model

Tags: wpf, checkbox, binding

So i have this `ListView` with `ItemSource` of my object and `ListViewItem`:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Select" Width="45">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <CheckBox Command="{Binding SelectedInterfaceCommand}"
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                                    </CheckBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
```

**ViewModelBase**

```
public ViewModelBase()
        {
            SelectInterfaceCommand = new SelectedInterfaceCommand(this);
        }
```

And i try to catch my `CheckBox` `IsChecked` event inside my `SelectedInterfaceCommand` `Command`:

```
public class SelectedInterfaceCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public ViewModelBase ViewModel { get; set; }

        public SelectedInterfaceCommand(ViewModelBase viewModel)
        {
            ViewModel = viewModel;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {

        }
    }
```

And my `CanExecute` and `Execute` never called.

I also try to this approach:

Inside my Object class i have this `Property`:

```
public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return isSelected; }
            set
            {
                isSelected = value;
                OnStaticPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

XAML

<GridViewColumn Header="Select" Width="45">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <CheckBox                                                
                                        <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                                            <Binding Path="IsSelected" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}"/>
                                        </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
```

And again this `IsSelected` setter never called.

Comment: From what I can see if your viewmodel is holding a collection of items, then command binding will not work unless you point the datacontext to a parent that is holding your viewmodel (currently it will look at the datacontext of a listviewitem which is `myObject`), you could solve it by using `RelativeSource`. `Checked` will never set because you're pointing to ListViewItrem, which  will set the property on UI element but not the underlying `myObject`.

Comment: Have you verified that the `DataContext` of the `CheckBox` is as you expect? You can check by handling its `Loaded` event and setting up a breakpoint inside the handler to check the `DataContext` property.

Comment: What's the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView`?